# Thoughts on modern promises

Tags: genealogy-of-morals

For a coming essay (university) I would like to analyze the modern concept of promises. However, I am having a fairly hard time **finding sources that have previously discussed the topic**.

Besides Nietzsche, do you remember any analysis of promises you can point me to? Thanks.

Comment: There's an essay by Tagore that briefly discusses the notion of keeping a promise or not; in the context of a response that Gandhi made on the same topic.

Comment: Sissela Bok's writings on lying overlap into the area of promises, as future behavior is one of the easiest things to lie about.

Comment: Promises are based on trust. Good book with many references - "Liars and Outliers:Enabling The Trust that Society Needs to Thrive" by Bruce Schneier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Kierkegaard discusses promises in his deliberation on loving the dead in *Works of Love*.

Specifically, the consideration in question is on what it means to have an obligation to one who is no longer living and how executing this is an act of love (in his vocabulary "work of love").

2. There's also some contemporary Kant-related literature on promise-making. Here, part of the question will be how promises obligate, whether we can make an immoral promise, once we do whether we are obligated.
3. There's some dense considerations that attend to promise making in Hegel's "lesser logic" that relate to implicit conditions in promises. (I've written on this myself).
4. There's considerations of promise-making as a ["speech act"](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/speech-acts/)